# Error: GTKMM 3.0 compiling error

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I have this error when compiling my first gtkmm project.

```
gtkmmgui.cpp:2:10: fatal error: gtkmm-3.0: No such file or directory
```

I also tried this:

```
g++ gtkmmgui.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm3.0`
```

but it still doesn't work.

Is this because of wrong #include directory?

Source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm-3.0>

int main() {
    Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);
    Gtk::Window window;
    Gtk::Window::run(window)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example which shows us your problem!

Comment: You have a lot of typos in your code example! You should try to compile your example code yourself and than really use copy&paste to the editor here! Compiling your example results in a lot of errors starting with: argc & argv undefined! So please be a bit more precise when asking questions! The working code is added to my answer, also the line which makes the code compile&link.

Comment: Did my answer help? Did it solve your problem? If so, please accept the answer so that other people can see it is a valid one. If you think the support was helpful, you can also upvote the answer. If you have further questions, please ask. It would be nice to get any feedback on answers with votes/accepts or questions. ;) Thats how SO works!

Comment: I also learned something from you, @Klaus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be nothing like

```
#include "gtkmm-3.0"
```

in your source.

Typically all includes look like:

```
#include <gtkmm/application.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>
```

You should provide also your source code here, because the error is something there! But please reduce it to the minimum where we can see your problem. Please never post all your code which is *not* related to the problem you ask for.

You also can check if your configuration of gtkmm is correct by simply looking in the output of you `pkg-config` command. Simply enter it on the command line:

```
> pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags
```

It should be something like:

```
-I/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtkmm-3.0/include < a lot more >
```

EDIT: Your example code is broken in so many parts! Please read the manual of gtkmm!

The following works:

```
#include <gtkmm/window.h>
#include <gtkmm/main.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);
    Gtk::Window window;
    kit.run(window);
    return 0;
}
```

compiled and linked with:

```
g++ `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` main.cpp
```

Comment: @CodingBasic: I will not follow external links! Please post your code in your question! And please *read* my answer! There is no `#include <gtkmm>` You have to include an *existing* file!

Comment: @CodingBasic Gtkmm headers should end with the `.h` extension, so you should try `#include <gtkmm.h>`, like in this [official example](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-basics-simple-example.html.en).